# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, dex

I implemented today Mobario SDK to my app and when I wanted to run this app this occurs in console:

```
[2013-09-15 16:37:05 - AppName] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/AdHitIdGenerator;
[2013-09-15 16:37:27 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/analytics/tracking/android/AdHitIdGenerator;
```

I tried to uncheck analytics and mobario .jar files from Build Path, but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone handled that one? Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

You have  included  the  **mobario .jar library** two times in your application that's why you get the error  !

Go to buildpath >  then move to libraries > remove the mobario.jar (you'll see option remover jar on rightside) and save

done

Now try to run/export your app

You have included same libraries with different names and location!

```
Close eclipse.
Delete bin folder inside your project folder.
Start eclipse and clean your project.
Now run and the problem should be gone
```

Comment: paste a screenshot of your project structure files in eclispe

Comment: @user2570350 open your Android private libraries and take the screenshot

Comment: @user2570350 Remove vnjferekanandh.jar from private lib it will work

Comment: @user2570350 Right click on your project go to properties > select android and take a screenshot and paste here

Comment: @user2570350 Right click on your project go to properties >  Go to java build path click on `order and export` take screenshot and click on `Libraries` and take screenshot!

Comment: http://i41.tinypic.com/116jq4x.png - Android, http://i41.tinypic.com/sg69w5.png - Export, http://i39.tinypic.com/2hqbfuq.png - Libs

Comment: @user2570350 what is the vnjferekanandh.jar file for ? which lib is that?

Comment: @user2570350 did you rename it?

Comment: @user2570350 where is the AdHitIdGenerator lib?

Comment: There is no such thing. I don't rename those since I don't want to mess with default names.

Comment: @user2570350 the problem you get is because there are two AdHitIdGenerator libraries in your project try removing one and  the problem will be solved

Comment: I can't locate them since they are not named AdHitIdGenerator.

Comment: Eclipse restored bin folder by cleaning function. Though, still the same problem :/

Comment: @user2570350 the only thing left to do is go go to properties > Go to java build path click on Libraries and remove all libraries you have added and add them again later and check

Answer (score 0):

Delete bin folder of your project and clean your project.

Its worked for Me

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this one. You have 2 jar files of the same type in the in the libs folder. Delete the one that you program doesn't need. I found this while testing the sample program, there were 2 tapfortap files in the libs folder. I checked the source and determined the one that wasn't used.

I also discovered that when upgrading to the latest SDK, several files were deleted during the upgrade process. I discovered because I was testing one of the programs which I originally implemented suddenly showed up with a lot of syntax errors. After several attempts of reloading all the files, everything came back to normal. The program does show more errors than I saw before, but on my android phone, everything seems to work fine. I find that the emulator is working slightly differently which I will need to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that with the SDK update, my original working space became corrupt, so I created a new one and loaded my project into it. Then everything is working fine.